# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file to_excel pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `concat` sheets in `xlsx` file and I found the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 832, in _get_writer
    yield file.write
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 772, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 931, in _serialize_xml
    write(" %s=\"%s\"" % (qnames[k], v))
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Projects/MyAuditPy/pd_read.py", line 265, in <module>
    join2.to_excel("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2175, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 738, in write
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 43, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 75, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 360, in write
    self.close()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 368, in close
    self.xf.close()
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 299, in get_stream
    pass
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 50, in element
    self._write_element(el)
  File "D:\Python Projects\MyAuditPy\venv\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 77, in _write_element
    xml = tostring(element)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1133, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 772, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 832, in _get_writer
    yield file.write
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 525, in __exit__
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 510, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 382, in _exit_wrapper
    callback(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

and this is my related code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx'

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client31_KPN')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client32_T-Mobile')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client33_Vodafone')

#shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns)
dataframes2 = [shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3]
join2 = pd.concat(dataframes2).reset_index(drop=True)

join2.to_excel("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx")
```

as the error in this line:

```
join2.to_excel("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx")
```

I need also some one suggest me how to perform a good way for a code like this

I hope someone could help me how can I solve this error

Comment: For one, your code can be greatly simplified by having the `pd.read_excel` read everything into a dict of DataFrames, which will be keyed by the sheet name. Then you'd iterate over the dict and perform those same operations (allowing you to only write it once). But that wont fix the error.

Comment: @ALollz thanks a lot for you support, could you give me an example for this as I have a lot of excels with a lot of sheets :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution that's because the limitation of rows in `xlsx` as I solved instead of converting `to_excel` is use `to_csv` as the below code:

```
join2.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.csv")
```